# For loops in R (unexpected symbol error)

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to calculate the overallMin in across 5 files that I have downloaded. The filenames all have the same format:

"2013-07-citibike.csv" "2013-08-citibike.csv"

"2013-09-citibike.csv" "2013-10-citibike.csv"

"2013-11-citibike.csv" "2013-12-citibike.csv"

I need to write a for loop that reads these files, calculates the min (of one particular column) for each file and then the overall min from all files.

So far I have this

```
numbers <- 07:12
filenames <- paste("2013-", numbers, "-citibike", ".csv", sep="")

overallMin <- 0
for (i in filenames) {
    trips <- read.csv(i)
    newMin <- min(trips)
    if (overallMin < newMin) {
        overallMin <- newMin
    }
}
overallMin
```

Confused with the csv part. Plus I am getting an Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in filenames) {                                                      trips = read.csv(i)            newMin"

> 

Comment: Why is your separator not defined (`sep=""`)?

Comment: I strongly suspect a typo, or you done't usnderstand that a capital-I is NOT the same as a lowercase i.  It would also be a bit strange to take the `min` of a n entire dataframe (but that's not the error.)

Comment: You'll see your problem almost immediate if you post `07:12` to the console (there is no leading 0). But this is just an issue with the names of the files, there will be problems with your other code too.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but why the `paste` function stuff? why you can just use  `x <- list.files()` and create a loop for read every `i in x` ?

Comment: Doesn't anybody actually read the error message?

Comment: Error messaging in R isn't always that helpful. Unless you have a secret decoder ring - then it's awesome.

Comment: Can we get `head(list.files())` Must check the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the file names directly. Another thing, you need to specify the column number, or you want the minimum of all file?

```
filenames <-c("2013-07-citibike.csv", "2013-08-citibike.csv",
              "2013-09-citibike.csv", "2013-10-citibike.csv",
              "2013-11-citibike.csv", "2013-12-citibike.csv")
```

or use `sprintf` to get the correct file names

```
numbers <- 07:12
filenames <- paste("2013-", sprintf("%02d",numbers), "-citibike", ".csv", sep="")

overallMin <- 1e80 #big number or the minimum will probably be zero
desirecol <- 2
for (i in filenames) {
  trips <- read.csv(i)
  newMin <- min(trips[,desirecol])
  if (overallMin < newMin) {
    overallMin <- newMin
  }
}
overallMin
```

Comment: I need to specify the column name. thanks for your help

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting this error message. Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '2013-07-citibike.csv': No such file or directory.  The file is actually there.

Comment: You need to specify to R the directory where you have the files: `setwd("c:/Your_directory/")`

Comment: Hi could you also please tell me how to find the min from a specific column? The column name is birth.year. So I tried putting $birth.year after trips in my code but its still showing the wrong value. Thanks so much for all your help so far.

Comment: Just make `desirecol <- "birth.year"` and also use `na.rm = TRUE` inside `min` if you have `NA`s

Answer (score 0):

The error message "unexpected symbol" almost always means a missing comma or parenthesis or some other silly syntax error. I must disagree with the thrust of @BrandonBertelson's comment. Reading error messages is *usually* helpful. In this case it is helpful to us in knowing the either there was an inappropriate substitution of `I` for `i` or that the poster did not post the exact error message or that there is a non-printing character that his editor inserted. I'm not able to reproduce the error by substituting an `I` for an `i`, since there is an `I()` function and the parser is correctly pointing out to me that I gave `read.csv()` an argument of the wrong type.

```
> for( i in 1:5) { my <- read.csv(I)}
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

The theory that the file names are wrong (and I agree that the code should have used `list.files` does NOT fit the error message. I can duplicate the error message by simply putting the first two lines on the same line:

```
> for( i in 1:5) { my <- read.csv(i) newMin <- min(trips[,desirecol])}
Error: unexpected symbol in "for( i in 1:5) { my <- read.csv(i) newMin"
```

For the specific question (aside form the error that remains obscure), this should succeed:

```
yourpath <- insert your path or getwd() if in working directory
colname  <- replace_with_column_name

min(                           #min of all the mins
    sapply( list.files( yourpath, pattern="citibike.*csv$),  #regex match
     function(f) min( read.csv(f)[[colname]]   # the columns rather than a whole dataframe
                       )  # returns the single mins
    )
```

Comment: Hi sorry the capital I was a type. In my code i am using lower case and still getting an error message

Comment: Post the exact copy pasted error message to replace the text in your question. Also paste the copied text from your console into your question.

Comment: this is the error message -Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in filenames) {                                                      trips = read.csv(i)            newMin"

Comment: I me this suggests that there is no semicolon or newline between `read.csv(i)` and `newMin`. The syntax of R requires a newline ... i.e. what is presented as a "\n" in R character variables between lines .... or the use of a semicolon.